# How to change multiple column values to a constant with out specifying all column names?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very wide dataframe in spark .It has 80 columns so I want to set a column to 0 and rest to 1.

So the one I want to set to 1 I tried it with

```
df = df.withColumn("set_zero_column", lit(0))
```

and it worked.

Now I want to set the rest columns  to 1. How do I do without specify all the 79 names ?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `select` with a list comprehension:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

set_one_columns = [lit(1).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c != "set_zero_column"]
df = df.select(lit(0).alias("set_zero_column"), *set_one_columns)
```

If you needed to maintain the original column order, you could do:

```
cols = [lit(0).alias(c) if c == "set_zero_column" else lit(1).alias(c) for c in df.columns]
df = df.select(*cols)
```

Comment: the seconds is preffered for this  question I guess.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I try to answer in **`Scala`**:

**`Example:`**

**`Method1:`**

```
//sample dataframe

val df=Seq(("a",1)).toDF("id","id1")

//filter req columns and add literal value

val cls=df.columns.map(x => if (x != "id1") (x,lit("1")) else (x,lit("0")))

//use foldLeft and add columns dynamically

val df2=cls.foldLeft(df){(df,cls) => df.withColumn(cls._1,cls._2)}
```

**`Result:`**

```
df2.show()
+---+---+
| id|id1|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
+---+---+
```

**`Method2:`**[`Pault`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault) approach :)

```
val cls=df.columns.map( x => if (x !="id1") lit(1).alias(s"${x}") else lit(0).alias(s"${x}"))
```

**`Result:`**

```
df.select(cls:_*).show()
+---+---+
| id|id1|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to spark SQL, although it may not be the most efficient way to handle this scenario but will be glad if it helps or can be further improved.

This is how I was able to do it in java:

Step #1:

Create Sparksession and load your file into dataframe.

Code:

```
public void process() throws AnalysisException {
    SparkSession session = new SparkSession.Builder()
         .appName("Untyped aggregation on data frame")
         .master("local")
         .getOrCreate();
    
    // Load the file that you need to compute. 
    Dataset<Row> peopledf = session.read()
        .option("header","true")
        .option("delimiter"," ")
        .csv("src/main/resources/Person.txt");
```

Output:

```
+--------+---+--------+
|    name|age|property|
+--------+---+--------+
|  Gaurav| 27|       1|
| Dheeraj| 30|       1|
|  Saloni| 26|       1|
|  Deepak| 30|       1|
|      Db| 25|       1|
|Praneeth| 24|       1|
|   jyoti| 26|       1|
+--------+---+--------+
```

Step 2 (optional):

In case you require to provide constant value to any one column.

Code:

```
// in case you require to change value for a single column.
Dataset<Row> peopledf1 = peopledf.withColumn("property",lit("0"));
peopledf1.show();
```

Output:

```
+--------+---+--------+
|    name|age|property|
+--------+---+--------+
|  Gaurav| 27|       0|
| Dheeraj| 30|       0|
|  Saloni| 26|       0|
|  Deepak| 30|       0|
|      Db| 25|       0|
|Praneeth| 24|       0|
|   jyoti| 26|       0|
+--------+---+--------+
```

Step 3:

Get the String array of all the column names in your data frame.

Code:

```
// Get the list of all the columns
String[] myStringArray = peopledf1.columns();
```

Step 4:

Logic for filtering out the column among the array you don't want to provide constant value to and creating List of required columns names and lit("constant") for withColumns

Code:

```
// create two list one being names of columns you need to compute
// other being same size (same number of element as that of column list) of 
// lit("0") i.e constant
// filter out the column that you don't want to apply constant to

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Column> myList1 = new ArrayList<Column>();

for (String element : myStringArray) {
    if (!(element.contains("name"))) {
        myList.add(element);
        myList1.add(lit("0"));
    }
}
```

Step 5:

Convert the List to Scala Seq as withColumns method requires that format of argument.

Code:

```
    //convert both list into scala Seq<Columns> and Seq<String> respectively.
    //Need to do this because withColumns method requires arguments in Seq form.
    //check scala doc for with columns
    Seq<Column> mySeq1 = convertListToSeq(myList1);
    Seq<String> mySeq= convertListToSeq1(myList);
```

code for convertListToSeq using JavaConverters:

```
   //Use JavaConverters to Convert List to Scala Seq using provided method below
    public Seq<String> convertListToSeq1(List<String> inputList) {
    return 
   JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(inputList.iterator()).asScala().
   toSeq();
   }

   public Seq<Column> convertListToSeq(List<Column> inputList) {
   return JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(inputList.iterator())
   .asScala().toSeq();
    }
```

Step6:

Print Output to console

Code:

```
    //Display the required output on console.
    peopledf1.withColumns(mySeq,mySeq1).show();
```

Output:

```
+--------+---+--------+
|    name|age|property|
+--------+---+--------+
|  Gaurav|  0|       0|
| Dheeraj|  0|       0|
|  Saloni|  0|       0|
|  Deepak|  0|       0|
|      Db|  0|       0|
|Praneeth|  0|       0|
|   jyoti|  0|       0|
+--------+---+--------+
```

Please do comment if code can be improved further.

Happy Learning,
Gaurav